# How to extract attribute from parent node

Tags: jquery, xml

Heres's a snippet of my XML file

```
<data page="1" totalpages="1" records="10" totalrecords="10">
    <storylistsview>
        <story_id>158</story_id>
```

I want to access the records attribute in the parent node. Could anyone simple explain how that can be done. I am able to access the rest of the xml just fine.

I tried `stage1 = $(xml).attr('records');`
and I have no luck

Comment: Works for me.  If it's an AJAX response, make sure the response return type is xml.

Comment: Please add a code snippet of how you're obtaining this xml in your javascript.  Is it an xml ajax call?

Comment: Is `xml` an xmldocument or an xml string. Also try `stage1 = $(xml).find('data').attr('records');`

Answer (score 0):

```
$($.parseXML(xml)).find('data').attr('records');
```

See working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AMzUH/2/).

Comment: Hey Musa, thank you for your help it works like a charm. I guess I was missing the .find, I need to located the node first? This is an awesome community, thanks all.